# Android draw bitmap to specific position on ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView sized 400 * 400 and a Bitmap sized 400 * 350.

I want to draw this Bitmap to the ImageView so that there is a blank region on the top of the ImageView. That is to say, draw from the coordinate (0, 50).

I am trying to find an API in ImageView like:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(int startXPos, int startYPos, int width, int height, Bitmap, bitmap);
```

But I only find one

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use the padding property to "move" the image, not sure if thats what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by overriding the onDraw() method. There is an API in Canvas class that enable the user to specify the coordinates to draw the bitmap.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, paint);
}
```